# Display recently awarded gold badges on sidebar (below hot network questions)

Tags: feature-request

Can we use the free space below the *Hot Network Questions* section to display recently awarded **gold** badges? No bronze or silver badges like it was done in the past. Just gold badges like for example:

- Great answer
- Great question
- Famous question
- ...

  [image]

Comment: I suggest we wait for the top bar changes to arrive on SU (see MSO).

Comment: With the recent layout change, I feel badges are less important